# How to find the column sum by restricting the row size in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, triangle

Having a data frame df1:

```
         DP 1     DP 2    DP 3   DP 4     DP 5    DP 6    DP 7   DP 8    DP 9    DP 10
OP 1    357848  1124788 1735330 2218270 2745596 3319994 3466336 3606286 3833515 3901463
OP 2    352118  1236139 2170033 3353322 3799067 4120063 4647867 4914039 5339085 
OP 3    290507  1292306 2218525 3235179 3985995 4132918 4628910 4909315     
OP 4    310608  1418858 2195047 3757447 4029929 4381982 4588268         
OP 5    443160  1136350 2128333 2897821 3402672 3873311             
OP 6    396132  1333217 2180715 2985752 3691712                 
OP 7    440832  1288463 2419861 3483130                     
OP 8    359480  1421128 2864498                         
OP 9    376686  1363294                             
OP 10   344014
```

I would like to calculate the sum of every column by restricting the row number.

`To calculate sum of first column data, Sum(DP1) where row size should be 10-1`

`To calculate sum of second column data, Sum(DP2) where row size should be 10-2`

`To calculate sum of Third column data, Sum(DP3) where row size should be 10-3`

and so on..

Output is like this:

```
    3327371  10251249  15047844  18447791  17963259  15954957  12743113  8520325  3833515
```

I tried to do with for loop:

```
>>dataframe_len = len(df1.columns)
>>print(dataframe_len)
   10
>>for i in range(0,10):
     #Here i need to find the sum of each column 
     #sum('col')(row size is 10-i)
```

it is not about DP1 to DP10(10 column) there are too many columns are there.

**Thank You For Your Time :)**

Comment: Does `10-1` mean `10 to 1` or `10 minus 1`? Ie are you trying the skip the top rows or the bottom rows? Based on  your expected output, it looks like skipping the bottom rows; or rather, skipping the last non-NA value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want it **as per your expected output** and not according to your description, `sum()` each column after dropping NA values and then skipping the last value:

```py
df.apply(lambda col: col.dropna()[:-1].sum())
```

Output:

```
DP 1      3327371.0
DP 2     10251249.0
DP 3     15047844.0
DP 4     18447791.0
DP 5     17963259.0
DP 6     15954957.0
DP 7     12743113.0
DP 8      8520325.0
DP 9      3833515.0
DP 10           0.0
```

---

*Side note:* Your sums are not rows 10-1, 10-2, 10-3 etc. They are rows 9-1, 8-1, 7-1. ie. You're skipping the *last* non-NA value of each column, not the top rows.

Ex `df['DP 1'].sum()` is `3671385` but skipping the last row `df['DP 1'][:-1].sum()` is `3327371` which matches with your expected output. For DP2: `df['DP 2'].sum()` is `11614543` and `df['DP 2'].dropna()[:-1].sum()` is `10251249` (your expected val) but `df['DP 2'][2:10].sum()` is `9253616`.

Comment: ah even better, +1. I overcomplicated with `shift(-1).last_valid_index()`

Comment: I started with what you had put (but couldn't get it to work since the shift amount per column is different). Then realised we're just skipping the last val.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of the information in column name when using `apply()`

```py
def sum_row(col):
    t = int(col.name.split(' ')[-1])
    return col.iloc[:-t].sum()

df_ = df.apply(sum_row)
```

```
# print(df_)

DP 1      3327371.0
DP 2     10251249.0
DP 3     15047844.0
DP 4     18447791.0
DP 5     17963259.0
DP 6     15954957.0
DP 7     12743113.0
DP 8      8520325.0
DP 9      3833515.0
DP 10           0.0
dtype: float64
```